# た時 vs てから vs たら vs 後で

Tags: grammar

I've been looking at example sentences, and explanations, but I'm still unable to fully understand the differences between these. Can someone give me a brief explanation, or give me a link that will help clear things up?

Comment: Related: [When is たら or 時 being preferred more than the other?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/50488/43676), [are たときに and たら equivalent?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/90810/43676), [Expressing the "after \[verb\]-ing", using 後で, -てから, 後に, 後から?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/9438/43676)

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/time-clauses/) is a link with てから、後（で）、and 時. [This](https://www.tofugu.com/japanese-grammar/conditional-form-tara/) article has a section on たら　as "when/after" and its usage. Hope these help:)